# How to move from intro slider to "real app"

Tags: react-native

So as the title says I'm new to this world and decided to create a small app as a test. I wanted an intro slider and found [this](https://github.com/Jacse/react-native-app-intro-slider) on GitHub. Separately I had made my app so I figured oh ok I can use this GitHub code and then just point it to my app when the state changes however, I'm not sure how do I do that.

Do I need to create another .js file where I enter the code and then have it call my current App.js? I know the "app" will be rendered when this if becomes true:

```
render() {
    if (this.state.showRealApp) {
      return <App />;
    } else {
      return <AppIntroSlider slides={slides} onDone={this._onDone}/>;
    }
  }
```

But I am unsure what should I put instead of just `<App />;` I am looking at the docs but I'm not sure of what I'm looking for so it's a bit of a moot point. Any pointers please?

Comment: change `showRealApp` state to `true` in `_onDone` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question wasn't very clear. so this is the method you'll have to follow in order to use external packages in your react-native app.

First download the package through NPM,

```
`npm install react-native-app-intro-slider`.
```

and import it where you call this

```
`<AppIntroSlider slides={slides} onDone={this._onDone}/>`
```

using `import AppIntroSlider from 'react-native-app-intro-slider';`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so looking at the repo for the slider they have simply given a skeleton of the sample. App basically means what you want to render.

To answer your question yes you can create a separate .js file where you have something rendering and then import that component and replace App with whatever you call that component. Or to make it work and make sure your importing and everything works you can just replace App with a View with some styling to see that it works when the state changes.

Make sure you import View or whatever component you decide to use.

For example you can use

```
render() {
if (this.state.showRealApp) {
  return <Text>Yay, it rendered properly</Text>;
} else {
  return <AppIntroSlider slides={slides} onDone={this._onDone}/>;
}
```

}

after importing Text from react-native